# Intent to start e-mail not showing Exchange Mail (Outlook) as an option

Tags: android-intent, outlook

I am using the following code from here to start an e-mail:

[Android: Using email intent to send email, possible to alter message just before sending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273949/android-using-email-intent-to-send-email-possible-to-alter-message-just-before)

The code is as follows:

```
private void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message) { 
try { 
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text"); 
    if (recipient != null)  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{recipient}); 
    if (subject != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject); 
    if (message != null)    emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message); 

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail...")); 

} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) { 
    // cannot send email for some reason 
}
```

}

When testing on my phone (HTC Desire) I don't get the option for using my Exchange/Outlook email (note I do when I click an e-mail link on the web for example).

Instead I get option for 'Gmail' and 'Evernote - Create Note' (very strange).

The code works as expected with Gmail, which is great, but I need it to work for Outlook.  Anyone got an idea what the issue is?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, but I asked this question twice (some time had passed between each post and I had forgot I had already asked!).

Anyway, found the solution here:  [How to open Email program via Intents (but only an Email program)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312438/how-to-open-email-program-via-intents-but-only-an-email-program)

*Changing the MIME type is the answer, this is what I did in my app to change the same behavior. I used intent.setType("message/rfc822");*

Worked like a dream!